# Definition of Include file

Tags: c++, c, include, header-files

I have seen a separation of [header files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html) in two Visual Studio folders,**Include Files** and **Header files**, where headers with public API have been in Include Files folder and others in Header files folder.

Is the term "include file" used and recognized this way? What I have seen is just the local project agreement or common practise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real distinction between the two. They're called include files almost certainly because you include them. They're called header files because they contain cut-down (header) information about the things they describe.

Either term will do, and seasoned C (and C++) coders should understand what you mean.

For what it's worth, the C standard uses "header names" or "headers" to describe them, since they're not required to be in files at all.